# How to say that action of living became easier?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I wanna say that process of living became better now. I could say `Life became easier`. But it's not exact form that I want. I wanna say that it's not life itself became so, but process of living.
I think like that: `It's became easier to live`. Is that correct ?

Comment: How come if the process of living has become easier, life is tough? Just asking!

Comment: First, you should say *I want to* not *I wanna*. Second, do you actually mean *your life became easier*? Or are you talking about *everybody's* lives? Also, what do you mean by *easier*? *Simpler*, *more enjoyable*, *healthier*, *less expensive*?

Comment: @Jason Bassford it's everybody's live. It's became simpler and also more cheerful.

Comment: @Maulik V what ?

Comment: What do you mean by "process"? What became easier? Was it because they were now near fresh water? Closer to transportation? That food was plentiful? Were earning a decent wage?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo let's say life in country in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpliest way to say what you are trying to express is

> **Life has become easier.**

If you say, without further context,

> **Life became easier**

most listeners will think something in *your* life has made *your* life easier.

There is also the well-known

> [**Summertime and the living is easy**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XivELBdxVRM)

Comment: +1 for *the living is easy*  :)

Answer (score 1):

> Life became easier.

This form is perfectly adequate to describe what you mean.  However if you're looking for alternative forms, you can also say:

> The quality of life has improved for me.

This is directly referring to how you deal with your life on a daily basis, perhaps suggesting a financial cause, but not necessarily.  This could also refer to a prosthetic allowing you to walk again, for instance.